iOS 18 Keeping a Control Widget up to date
In iOS 18, we have the ability to add custom widget in ControlCenter. And also we have an AppIntentControlValueProvider, so we can update the widget state when the user presses it.
Is there a way to update the ControlWidget with a timer or an event from inside the application?

I've filed a request to Apple... so far I couln't find it.

I've found a solution:

We can bind data from our application and Widget using SharedPreferences.
When we update data in our application, we can update the data in SharedPreferences and force update the widget with either

this
ControlCenter.shared.reloadAllControls()

or this
ControlCenter.shared.reloadControls(ofKind: "your-widget-kind")


My bad, I misread the question. Your described way works for sure. However for my use case this is not enough, since the data updates by time without opening the app.

@Meyssam, it's probably the only one way of doing that is to add background permissions to your app and then in background use methods of reloading the widget from the app.
